# Making Celery returning a Future

Tags: python, celery, tornado

I am using the tornado web framework. Is it possible to make a celery task returning an object of the [Future](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future) class, in order to use it in an @gen.coroutine decorated handler?

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
    class TornadoRequestHandler(BaseHandler):

         @gen.coroutine
         def get(self):
              result = yield celery_task.apply_aync()
              self.write(result)
              self.finish()
```

I've seen [tornado-celery](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery), but that isn't exactly what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is via tornado-celery, which will let you do this:

```
class TornadoRequestHandler(BaseHandler):

     @gen.coroutine
     def get(self):
          result = yield gen.Task(celery_task.apply_aync)
          self.write(result)
          self.finish()
```

The reason is that the behavior you want when using `gen.coroutine` relies on all the async methods it calls to take a `callback` kwarg, which gets called when the method completes. `celery_task.apply_async` doesn't take a `callback` kwarg, so `gen.coroutine` can't be used directly. It looks like `tornado-celery` works by exploiting the fact that `apply_async` does take an `**options` parameter, which can be any arbitrary kwargs. This means that `apply_async` actually will accept a `callback` kwarg, but just ignore it. `tornado-celery` takes advantage of this by overriding the class in Celery responsible for publishing tasks, and changes the publishing process to publish your task, and then consume from the result queue that gets published to when the tasks completes. The consuming code executes the function provided by the normally ignored `callback` kwarg, which it pulls out `**options`.

I'm not sure how clear that explanation, was, but the tl;dr version is tornado-celery provides the simplest way of getting as close possible to the behavior you want.

Comment: HI dano! Thank you for your answer. I think so, too :), and tornado-celery is a nice library, but now i solved it by running the celery tasks in an executor, using a caller function that waits for the task to be finished. It s little code and it wokrs with tornado standard tools.

Comment: the concept of result for `gen` and celery's `apply_async` are quite different, one is future in ioloop, another one is future in task queue. The later one should be gotten be result.get() while the prior one is by `yield`. However, the tornado-celery mixed them altogether.